# API Design Flaw with Factory Pattern

Tags: c++, api, pointers, factory

I'm using a factory to create `Shape` instances for a physics engine. The size of each shape is not known until construction time, hence a factory being used in place of stack memory + cloning. A `Shape` is then supplied to the physics `Scene` to create a `Body`:

```
// Sphere derives from Shape
Sphere *s = Scene.CreateSphere( radius );

// Construct a rigid body with a certain shape
Body *b = Scene.CreateBody( s );
```

**The issue**: I wish for each `Shape` to be associated with only one `Body` at any given time. I need to disallow the user from doing this:

```
Body *b1 = scene.CreateBody( );
Body *b2 = scene.CreateBody( );
Shape *s = scene.CreateBox( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );
b1->AddShape( s );
b2->AddShape( s ); // bad
```

---

**Additional info**: Expensive performance checks for pointer uniqueness would be best to be avoided, as performance is important here. However in debug mode performance hits for error checking are acceptable.

It is important to be able to construct shapes separately from creating bodies, as multiple shapes can be apart of an aggregate rigid body:

```
Body *b = Scene.CreateBody( );
b->AddShape( shapePtr1 );
b->AddShape( shapePtr2 );
```

`Shape` instances should also be able to be transferred from one `Body` to another during run-time;

```
Body *b1, b2; // initialized elsewhere
Shape *s;     // initialized elsewhere, is attached to b1
b1->RemoveShape( s );
b2->AddShape( s );
```

Perhaps I should go about a different api design? Perhaps cloning could be used somehow?

Comment: Show us the actual error...

Comment: @EdS. Right, got it up there now.

Comment: Even if you could achieve what you want, what's to forbid the user from copying the pointer first and calling the function again with the copy of the pointer? Your design is wrong.

Comment: This is what `std::unique_ptr` is for

Comment: @Syam that is true. I would accept as an answer a different way of going about this altogether.

Comment: @RandyGaul Without knowing what you *really* want to achieve, giving a correct answer will be very hard. MooingDuck's comment is probably the best you'll get without giving us a lot more details.

Comment: You'll have to show us a bit more than what you have here in that case.

Comment: Hmm okay, I'll add some more details to my post!

Comment: If I'm understanding the problem correctly, once a shape's associated with a body, you want to disallow that shape from being add to another body?

Comment: @greatwolf Yes exactly. More specifically, the memory of a shape cannot be associated with more than one body at any given time.

Comment: `const Type *p;` is not a constant pointer - it is a pointer to a `const Type`

Comment: Okay re-wrote the question since this is a design issue, not a compilation issue.

Comment: Is there a reason to allow a `Shape` that is not associated with any `Body`?

Comment: @Beta There should be support to disconnect a `Shape` from a `Body` and attach it to another `Body`. There should also be support to attach a `Shape` to a `Body` at any time. Other than these, no.

Comment: As @MooingDuck said, instead of raw pointer, use unique_ptr and you will achieve this behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make all your `Create*()` functions take a `Body` parameter, as a form of *dependency inversion*.

Then you can only create a `Shape` for a single `Body`.  You can also assert or otherwise error out if you try to create a `Shape` on a `Body` that already has a shape.

You can support the moving of `Shape` objects with the simple requirement that the destination `Body` does not already have an attached `Shape`.  Do not have a `DetachShape`, which would allow "dangling" shapes, but rather simply a `MoveShapeTo` and a `ReleaseShape`.  Alternatively, just use a smart pointer of some variety to ensure that "dangling" shapes are cleaned up properly, if that's your primary worry.

Comment: And what about supporting multiple shapes on a single body? A body can be an aggregate of many shapes.

Comment: Don't forget to lock down the `Shape` copy ctor and assignment operator.

Comment: Just do that then.  Allow `Body` to be passed to `Create*()` multiple times, make sure `DetachShape` take a specific `Shape` instance in some fashion, same for `MoveShapeTo`.

Answer (score 1):

Make `Body::AddShape(...)` private, and remove the ctor that takes a `Shape*` argument.

```
void Body::AddSphere(float radius)
{
  AddShape(Scene.CreateSphere(radius));
}

void Body::transferShape(Shape *s, Body &B2)
{
  RemoveShape( s );
  B2.AddShape( s );
}

// Construct a rigid body with no Shapes (yet)
Body *b = Scene.CreateBody();

// Give it a Sphere
b->AddSphere(radius);

// Transfer it to another body:
Body *b2 = Scene.CreateBody();
Shape *s = b->GetShapePointerSomehow();
b->transferShape(s, *b2);
```

Note that there is no way to add a preexisting `Shape` to a `Body` without removing it from another `Body`. No outside code can cause two Bodies to contain the same `Shape`.